Github pages-Airtable PAT best practices
I have a website hosted on Github pages which is pulling data from an Airtable database. Airtable now requires the use of personal access tokens to query data.
What's the best approach to do this that avoids including the token itself in the repository and website pages?
Is using Github codespaces a viable solution?
